# Does removing a memory module and sticking it back in fix memory errors

Tags: memory

I ran Window's memory diagnostic tool after having a lot of crashes that indicated memory problems and it reported a problem. I then took out the memory module (a DDR3 soDIMM module) to write down the part number. I also blew out any dust and re-inserted the module and then ran the memory diagnostic tool again but this time it didn't report any problems. I'll have to use the computer during the day to see if the crashes still happen.

Is it possible though that by removing a memory module and re-inserting it that it might clean up any grunge on the pins that result in fixing the problem, or is it far more likely that the memory problem is really internal in the module and will eventually come back? Many years ago, it was possible for grunge to built up on pins but I suspect that those days are long over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those days aren't over. Whenever you work with metals, there will be some sort of oxidation. Depending on the environment you use your laptop in, this can be faster / more severe. By removing and reinserting the module, you mechanically rubbed anything off that could have been tampering with your ram.

Another option is that, through moving around, the ram module was slightly moved in it's slot. So by putting it back in properly, you fixed the issue. There are a lot of small parts to a laptop, that can be more or less of a hassle. To make sure, just see what happens in the next few days, but my best guess is you've fixed your problem.